# Why isn't this iterating through a json dataset and pushing data into an array using GAS?

Tags: json, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code below generates an output and I am trying to push some of this data into an array.
The log shows data, but the iteration doesn't seem to work.

```
const API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

function getcandidates() {
  const url = 'https://api.catsone.com/v3/candidates';

  const params = {
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'method': 'GET',
    'redirect': 'follow',
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Token ' + API_KEY
    }
  };
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  const getText = response.getContentText();
  const dataSet = JSON.parse(getText);
  Logger.log(dataSet);
  let rows = [],
    data;
  for (let i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet[i];
    Logger.log(data) //Nothing gets logged here
    rows.push([data.desired_pay, data.contact_id, data.date_created, data.is_registered]);
  }
}
```

Here's the output of the first log, with highlighted "fields" I'd like to get:
[image]

Comment: Add the log as text not as image.  Also be more descriptive about what the script should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your sample image, it seems that `dataSet` is like `{_embedded: {candidates: [,,,]}}`. The values of `desired_pay`, `contact_id`, `date_created`, `is_registered` you want to retrieve are in the array. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const dataSet = JSON.parse(getText);
```

#### To:

```
const dataSet = JSON.parse(getText)["_embedded"]["candidates"];
```

- From your sample image, I couldn't correctly confirm whether the key for the array is `_embedded` and `candidates`. So please check it again.

Comment: Savior! Thank you!

Comment: @Antonio Santos Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Still a lot for me to learn and practicing it is the best way and it is only possible with your help. Thank you!